# upload file to another sub domain application from main domain application in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have some problem, i need to upload file to sub domain application from main domain application, but i can't do it. I have a main domain which is codeigniter application and have some others sub domain codeigniter application, but my all applications admin panel is placed into main domain application. If i use base url than it's show main domain base path but i can't get sub domain base url from main domain application.

Comment: Do you mind to show the code?
What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You have not posted any code to go by. But will give it ago

if your setup something like this example on server

```
application

system 

index.php

subdomain >

subdomain > uploads
```

Then to upload to folder in subdomain try

**Controller Where Upload Function is on Main Application**

```
$config['upload_path'] = FCPATH . 'subdomain-name/uploads/';
```

Or

```
$config['upload_path'] = './subdomain-name/uploads/';
```

**Note:** check uploads folder permission 777

All ways good to read userguide

CI2: http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/file_uploading.html

CI3: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

Make sure you include the field name on the do_upload. Field name is input name="userfile"

```
$field_name = "userfile";
$this->upload->do_upload($field_name)
```

On The view then would be

```
<input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />
```